# How to fix a bug where a tkinter button command calling itself does not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter

I want to have a button that has a command which quit/destroys a few other objects, including itself:

example:

```
B1 = Button(root, command= delete) # contains other settings too
def delete():
    B1.destroy()
    # contains destruction of other objects too
```

example code of it in the script(incomplete):

```
def mainpage():
    signup_btn = Button(root,text="Sign-Up", width=10, height=3, font=("courier", 16, "bold"), command=signup_page())
    signup_btn.place(relx=0.5 , rely=0.4, anchor=(CENTER))
    login_btn = Button(root,text = "Log-In", width=10, height=3, font=("courier", 16, "bold"), command=login_page())
    login_btn.place(relx=0.5 , rely=0.6, anchor=(CENTER)) 


    def signup_page():
        # destroy previous page
        signup_btn.destroy()
        login_btn.destroy()

        # setup new page
        title = Label(root, text="Enter your username and password, then press save and proceed to the log-in page!", height= 4, width=30, font=("courier", 16, "bold"))
        title.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=TOP)





    def login_page():
        signup_btn.destroy()
        login_btn.destroy()
```

in this case, the login_btn contains a function, calling to destroy itself and another button. this causes an error because if I place the UDF above the button's initialisation, the UDF has an error because the button being called inside is not initialised and vice versa if I put the button above the UDF

this causes an error in which when the button is initialised, the command does not exist. and if i initiate the command first, the button does not exist. its not just this specific scenario, it happen many times throughout the script where i an trying to call a variable/udf that is not yet created but its the same the other way round.

for some reason,e it works in 1 part of the script but the same logic works nowhere else. so i think im missing something about the part that works

i tried classes, different structures, or editing the button afterwards but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `command=signup_page()` to `command=lambda: signup_page()` and `command=login_page()` to `command=lambda: login_page()`

You could also write your program using classes, it should look somewhat like this:

```py
from tkinter import *


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry("720x480")
        self.title('Test')

        self.signup_btn = Button(self, text="Sign-Up", width=10, height=3,
                                 font=("courier", 16, "bold"), command=self.signup_page)
        self.signup_btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=(CENTER))

        self.login_btn = Button(self, text="Log-In", width=10, height=3,
                                font=("courier", 16, "bold"), command=self.login_page)
        self.login_btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=(CENTER))

    def signup_page(self):
        # destroy previous page
        self.signup_btn.destroy()
        self.login_btn.destroy()

        # setup new page
        title = Label(self, text="Enter your username and password, then press save and proceed to the log-in page!",
                      height=4, width=30, font=("courier", 16, "bold"))
        title.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=(N))

    def login_page(self):
        self.signup_btn.destroy()
        self.login_btn.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for the solution it worked perfectly, but, may I ask you how to use this class? below is my code, I'm trying to run the function: .starting() inside the class called final. the contents of .starting() are those inside the other courses. thanks in advance !

```
class PageHome:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def home_page_setup(self):
    # code
class PageSchedule(PageHome):
    def everything():
    # code

class final(PageSchedule):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def starting(self):
        self.home_page_setup()
        self.everything()
```

Comment: You have to first create an instance of the class, then call the method on that instance. This means in final you have to do for example `new = PageHome()` and then you can do  `new.home_page_setup()`

Comment: that worked. but now there is a separate error. the code is: class pages(): def homepage(): labelHome = Label(root, text="Home", font=("Courier",16,"bold"), height=3, width=15)  

that is for the first UDF which is the creation of multiple objects. then for the error:

def delete_mainpage():
self.labelHome.destroy()

the error message is: AttributeError: 'Pages' object has no attribute 'labelHome'

extra info: in the first UDF, there is a button that has a command that leads it to the second UDF. 

i thought that all the objects within the class would be accesible via the .self

Comment: You have to write `self.labelHome = Label(root, text="Home", font=("Courier",16,"bold"), height=3, width=15)` in the Pages class because right now as you have it labelHome is not an attribute of the Pages class and `self.labelHome.destroy()` won't work

Comment: There's no need to use `lambda` here. `command=login_page` and `command=signup_page` is sufficient.